# Android App and AVD rotating

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, autorotate

I`m new in programming Android and have a few beginner problems.
I want to rotate my app, when I rotate the device.

How can I programm that my App do this?

And I want to test it with the AVD, but in my AVD, I can not rotate the browser. My AVD has a acclerometer, so what must I do that my own app and the browser rotate?

---

I can rotate the emulator. But the applications in the emulator do not rotate.I want to rotate my own application. I dont know the sourcecode. This was my first question. 
my second one, is why no application like the browser in the AVD rotate when I rotate the AVD.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/introducing-android-emulator-managing-android-virtual-devices-avd

Answer (score 1):

To rotate emulator press Ctrl+F11. Your app should rotate without adding any code.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't fully understand what you meant in your question, please be more specific.

But if you mean to rotate the AVD you can press `KEYPAD_9, Ctrl-F12, KEYPAD_7 or Ctrl-F11` (for the other virtual keys see [Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#controlling))